# meaning of "A group of graduate students planned to picket a movie theater that would not show a sexually explicit foreign film"

Tags: meaning

meaning of: "A group of graduate students planned to picket a movie theater that would not show a sexually explicit foreign film"

does it mean that students protested for showing a sexually film? or did they agree with showing this kind of film?

Comment: If they planned to picket (i.e. to protest) it seems pretty obvious they disagreed with the decision taken by the movie theater not to show the film.

Answer (score 2):

They protested against the movie theater for not showing the film. So they felt that the theater should in fact show the film, and were annoyed that they refused to show it.

The opposite of this fantastic scene from Father Ted:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gT9xuXQjxMM

If the theater was showing a film they didn't want shown, it would be

> A group of graduate students planned to picket a movie theater that chose to show a sexually explicit foreign film”